# Writing lines to file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, file, newline

Knowing that writing multiple lines was asked million times before:

The commonly recommended way to that seems to be joining the lines with \n like this:

```
f = open("fileName", "a")
ptMembers = ['hello', 'world']
trackPoint = '/n'.join(ptMembers)
f.write(trackPoint)
```

The expectation would be to see in the file this:

```
hello
world
```

In reality the newline literal \n finds its way into the file like this:

```
hello\nworld
```

Why is it? And can it be overridden other than writing each line separately?

Comment: How are you inspecting the contents of the file?

Comment: First, the slash is the wrong direction in your example code, but the right direction in your example output so I think that's just a typo. Aside from that, Windows delimits new lines with `\r\n` with `\r` meaning carriage return and `\n` meaning new line.

Comment: @ScottHunter: notepad

Comment: @SyntaxVoid: unfortunately the typo was in the code as well :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by SyntaxVoid, there is a typo in the question - which was copied from the code. That was the whole problem.